# I would like to add a string after 'script' at JHtml::_('script', $file, true, true);

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, captcha

Inside the recaptcha.php file of the Recaptcha Plugin on Joomla 3.6, I have the following code:

```
case '2.0':
            $theme = $this->params->get('theme2', 'light');
            $file  = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=' . JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag() . '&amp;render=explicit';

            JHtml::_('script', $file, true, true);

            $document->addScriptDeclaration('jQuery(document).ready(function($) {$(window).load(function() {'
                . 'grecaptcha.render("' . $id . '", {sitekey: "' . $pubkey . '", theme: "' . $theme . '"});'
                . '});});'
            );
            break;
```

Which creates the string:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en-US&amp;render=explicit" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

loading the api.js for the recaptcha.
Since I am using Rocket Loader from Cloudflare I would like to change this

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en-US&amp;render=explicit" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to this

```
<script data-cfasync="false" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en-US&amp;render=explicit" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

where after the

I tried using a variable $cloud = 'data-cfasync="false"'; and changing JHtml::*('script', $file, true, true); to JHtml::*('script', $cloud, $file, true, true); or I tried JHtml::script data-cfasync="false" ($file, true, true); or JHtml::*('script data-cfasync="false"', $file, true, true); or JHtml::*('script'.'data-cfasync="false"', $file, true, true);
And nothing worked....... 
I know some of them are stupid but I am not a real programmer as you have figured out already.
How can I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As of Joomla 3.7, the arguments for `JHtml` were updated whilst keeping backward compatibility.

So rather than passing `, true, true`, you need to pass an array of options, then an array of attributes, like so:

```
JHtml::_('script', $file, array('version' => 'auto'), array('data-cfasync' => false));
```

You can have a look at the source code here: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/src/HTML/HTMLHelper.php#L679

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

OK the answer came from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52953066/i-would-like-to-add-a-string-after-script-at-jhtml-script-file-true-t where I posted the same question. In Joomla version 3.4.8 that I have on the website the way to put a string inside the  tags is:

```
$script = '<script src="' . $file . '" data-cfasync="false"></script>';
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addCustomTag($script);
```

I thank you very much
I appreciate your help
Best Regards
George